# Boot Windows 8 from another disk

Tags: grub2, windows-8, ssd

I'm trying to add a Windows 8 SSD to the boot menu. But what I only have achieved is a blank screen after selecting the custom menu entry for Windows 8. I've no problems to boot Windows 8 when I switch the boot order by using the UEFI.

This is my custom menu entry:

```
menuentry "Windows 8" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    set root='(hd1)'
    drivemap -s hd0 hd1
    chainloader (hd1)+1
}
```

Here is the output from boot info script:

```
      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   216,768,511   216,766,464  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         216,770,558   250,068,991    33,298,434   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         216,770,560   250,068,991    33,298,432  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15505 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sdb1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sdb

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048       616,447       614,400 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sdb2         616,448       821,247       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sdb3         821,248     1,083,391       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sdb4       1,083,392   225,062,911   223,979,520 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771   ext4       
/dev/sda5        4c4e44af-28a9-46fa-85fd-f416bfaf92cd   swap       
/dev/sdb1        5220B52F20B51AC5                       ntfs       Wiederherstellung
/dev/sdb2        1AB6-57AC                              vfat       
/dev/sdb4        B632C3B732C37B3F                       ntfs          

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /                        ext4       (rw,noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1        /media/user/Wiederherstellung fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb4        /media/user/B632C3B732C37B3F fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=countdown
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --verbose --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
    set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 ro  
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-advanced-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-35-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-recovery-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-35-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-26-generic-advanced-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic root=UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-26-generic-recovery-a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic root=UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows 8" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    set root='(hd1)'
    drivemap -s hd0 hd1
    chainloader (hd1)+1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a9021806-ff94-4422-8272-42cc96a25771 /               ext4    discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro    0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4c4e44af-28a9-46fa-85fd-f416bfaf92cd none            swap    sw                                   0       0
# temporary directories as tmpfs
tmpfs                                     /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777,size=2G   0       0
tmpfs                                     /var/log        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777,size=128M 0       0
# external device
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb2

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 02 fe 19  |.X.MSDOS5.0.....|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 68 09 00  |........?....h..|
00000020  00 20 03 00 01 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |. ..............|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 ac 57 b6 1a 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..).W..NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 4d 65  |..............Me|
000001b0  64 69 65 6e 66 65 68 6c  65 72 ff 0d 0a 4e 65 75  |dienfehler...Neu|
000001c0  73 74 61 72 74 3a 20 54  61 73 74 65 20 64 72 81  |start: Taste dr.|
000001d0  63 6b 65 6e 0d 0a 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |cken............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 bb 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc sdd sde sdf sdg 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-eO3hpoLX/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to add the partition but it leads me always to the message:

```
no such partition...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using UEFI, I would recommend to install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead of GRUB. It's much easier and should work without configuration even with external disks.

Comment: Ok, good luck with that.

Comment: It was pretty easy :). My fault was, that Ubuntu has used BIOS and Windows UEFI, as you can see above. After re installing Ubuntu by forcing UEFI it worked flawless ;).

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved. :) Out of 3-4 laptops with UEFI on which I installed Ubuntu, two weren't able to boot GRUB properly until using rEFInd. That's why I am starting to suggest it all over the place, it works quite well. But as long as GRUB doesn't give problems, that's perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used BIOS mode for Ubuntu and UEFI mode for Windows. After I switched to UEFI mode through some settings of my Motherboard and reinstalled Ubuntu it worked flawlessly.

[This answer is related](https://askubuntu.com/a/281856/285111)