# Is booting to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS through Legacy boot mode from safe?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, bios

So I recently just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Gnome flavor on my new 128GB SanDisk USB drive. Under my Bios boot mode settings, with *UEFI* selected, only my ubuntu live usb can be seen whenever I get to the boot manager (F12). But in *Legacy* boot mode under my Bios settings, I am able to boot into either my live usb, windows or the intended ubuntu 16.04 LTS flash drive.

I am happy the USB drive now works but being still fairly new to this booting method I'm worried as to whether there are any **risks** or **disadvantages** using *Legacy* boot considering I have Windows 10 installed on my internal SSD.

So is it **safe**? Is there a way to keep my boot mode in *UEFI* and boot my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS USB without having to tamper with my internal storage?

Comment: Your Windows is installed in legacy-mode. No reason to worry about. I have three operating installed on two drives, everything in legacy-mode, works flawless. Your USB-flash-drive is shown under both boot-modes because it is bootable in both modes. UEFI is new and bring some advantages  which are not really needed in small home computer. Legacy-mode is safe, it has been the standard for many, many years.

Comment: @mook765 I just realized I can't boot from my windows from Legacy mode. It just automatically boots from the ubuntu usb flash drive instead. This is the exact opposite of my problem using UEFI (can't boot Ubuntu but it automatically boots windows). I'm lost at what to do.

Comment: So what happens when you boot to your 128GB SanDisk USB drive. Do you get the Grub-menu then where you can choose Ubuntu or Windows ?

Comment: @mook765 no unfortunately, it gives me the boot manager and there is see all my HDDs and My Ubuntu Flash drive listed as a HDD. I select it and it goes straight to ubuntu and shows me the login screen for my ubuntu user account. But I have managed to make some progress. My laptop is an Acer Aspire E 15 so it has an option for **"Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"** under the  _Security_ tab in the Bios. Selecting it i navigate to HDD1 > ubuntu > grubx64.efi . Mind you I have no idea why this is here since this computer is fairly  new and I have not installed ubuntu to **any** of ...

Comment: @mook765 ... my internal drives, only to this 128GB usb stick. I select grubx64.efi set its description as **'grub boot'** and i allow it as a trusted. I save and lo and behold on restart, after hiting F12  the boot manager now displays both my windows boot and **grub boot**. I select grub boot and it takes me to the GNU GRUB Version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2 terminal. From which i followed [this tutorial on booting from grub terminal](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux). Thankfully it worked and i faced my log in screen again, but now there is another problem as...

Comment: @mook765 ... I have to type in that code at the grub terminal each time i want to use Ubuntu OS.  The Code I used was:    `grub> set root=(hd0,1)  grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1  <------(in my case this was sdc1)  grub> initrd /initrd.img  grub> boot`

Comment: Could you run [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and create a boot-info-summary? Then post URL so we can see how your system is configured.

Comment: @mook765 here it is http://paste2.org/782yDMVa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a bit longer, so I am unable to post it as a comment.

You have three drives attached to your system.The first drive `sda` has two partitions, sda1 is a `Microsoft reserved partition`, maybe a leftover from a former Windows-installation on the drive. `sda2` is a NTFS-partition, data-storage.
The drive has a GPT-partition-table.

On your second drive `sdb` your recent Windows is installed in UEFI-mode, ESP-partition `sdb1` is on this drive. GPT-partition-table.

On your third drive `sdc`you just installed Ubuntu, but in legacy-mode, this is the point creating your headache. You should have installed in UEFI-mode.
The drive has MBR-partition-table.

You should convert this drive from MBR to GPT, you can use Gparted to do that.
Then install Ubuntu again, but install in UEFI-mode. You have to boot the installer in UEFI-mode to do that, how you boot is how it installs.
Grub will be installed on the ESP-partition off the internal drive. By default Grub will be installed on the ESP of `sda`. This fact leads to the next issue.

The ESP-partition should be on the first drive `sda`, but just right now it is on the second drive `sdb`. That may lead to boot-problems.
I don't know if it is possible to change the drives in your laptop, that would solve this issue. If the second drive is an external drive too, then you have to leave it as it is.

Before doing all that you may try the suggested repair by running Boot-repair again (click `recommended repair`-button) and see if it works properly.
I have my doubts...

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231306/booting-multiple-oss-from-multiple-disks-with-uefi) and that leads me to another idea.
You want to install in UEFI-mode, but you don't want your Windows-drive to be affected in any way. You may try this:

Detach the Windows-drive from the Laptop. Install Ubuntu on the external drive in UEFI-mode. Create ESP-partition on this drive during install (ca.500MB FAT, boot-flag). After install finished reattach the Windows-drive.
Boot to external drive to start Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub`, so the OS-prober can find Windows and creates Grub-menu-entry. Set boot-order in UEFI-BIOS to external drive. In the case the external drive is not attached you would have to change boot-order to Windows-drive.

No warranty, I can't test that due to missing equipment. But [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474282/how-to-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-using-uefi-and-two-hdds/474307) you can see that I am not the first with this idea...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort mook765. It finally worked. I loaded up the live usb in UEFI mode repartition the 128GB flash drive as GPT and then proceeded to reinstall Ubuntu on it. Rebooted, at first it didn't show up but then i went to my BIOS and selected option "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" under the Security tab in the Bios. Selecting it i navigate to HDD1 > ubuntu > grubx64.efi. After adding the description as **grub** and saving i rebooted and hit F12 for boot manager. There it was **grub**, I select it and the grub selection menu comes up. THANKS LOTS! :D